# How specify filename and store_dir when carrierwave uploader not associated with a Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

The non-Model-based uploading works fine using the code below, I just need to see how to specify the `filename`, and specify a `store_dir`.

My Rails 4.2 app uploads some remote PNGs, convert them to JPG, then store on S3, but the images are not associated with any Model field. Carrierwave version (0.10.0)

In the Carrierwave docs I cannot see how to specify an arbitrary store_dir and filename for an instance of the uploader to use. (When bound to a Model, specifying a name *derived* from Model parameters and/or random tokens is well documented by overriding the filename() and store_dir() methods and accessing model parameters within the methods).

But when there is no associated model field, how does one "pass in" to an instance of an uploader the desired filename and store_dir to use?

```
# working ruby code to upload a couple of PNGs not associated with any Model

u = next_url_to_copy() # http://example.com/tom.png
uploader = SnapshotUploader.new
# HOW SPECIFY DESIRED DESTINATION FILENAME 
# "tom.jpg" AND SUB-FOLDER "tom_stuff" ??
open(u) { |file| something = uploader.store!(file) }
puts "#{uploader.filename}"
# open-uri20160516-982-xxxxxx # filename created by Carrierwave

u = next_url_to_copy() # http://example.com/harry.png
uploader = SnapshotUploader.new
# HOW SPECIFY DESIRED DESTINATION FILENAME 
# "harry.jpg" AND SUB-FOLDER "harry_stuff" ??
open(u) { |file| something = uploader.store!(file) }
puts "#{uploader.filename}"
# open-uri20160516-982-yyyyy # filename created by Carrierwave


# SnapshotUploader.rb
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'

class SnapshotUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

  def store_dir
    "#{Settings.root_picture_folder}/snapshots"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url
    Settings.missing_picture_flyer
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  process :convert => 'jpg'
  process :set_content_type

  def set_content_type(*args)
    self.file.instance_variable_set(:@content_type, "image/jpg")
  end
end
```

The uploader class does not seem to provide a "setter" for the filename or store_dir, nor can I find attributes to set directly. The usual method (when the uploader is associated with a Model) of overriding filename() and store_dir() to use a model parameter won't work, since there is no model associated with the uploader.